# How to make Cordova camera window size small like scanner

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera, android-camera

I want to have a small camera window like a scanner (need more small). 
[image: What I need]

With current [camera plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) I am using, It doesn't have such option. Please help me with this.

In my current project, I would like to scan a book page no. and work with it. I am able to scan the whole page and get the content with [ocr plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mobile-ocr) but I want to capture only page number.